# Slow remote mysql with VB.net- need to speed up

Tags: mysql, vb.net, performance

I'm using vb.net and mysql( from a shared hosting) with the following code

```
    Public conn As OdbcConnection
        Public da As OdbcDataAdapter
        Public ds As DataSet
        Public dr As OdbcDataReader
        Public cmd As OdbcCommand
        Public MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
        Public xc As MySqlCommand
        Public xd As MySqlDataAdapter
        Public serv As String, user As String, pass As String, db As String
Sub connect()
            serv = "xyz.com"
            user = "abc"
            pass = "mypasword" 
            db = "mydb"
            MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
            MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & serv & ";" & "UserID=" & user & ";" & "password=" & pass & ";" & "database=" & db & ";Character Set=utf8;"
            Try
                MysqlConn.Open()
                MysqlConn.Close()
            Catch myerror As Exception
                MsgBox("Connection Error")
            End Try
End Sub
```

Now any select, insert or update action takes more that 5 seconds and freezes the whole application. But my client wants it faster. How can I speed it up? is that the hosting or mysql or connection method - which is to upgrade or alter with other to make it faster?

Thanks

Comment: You could set the `MakeMyDatabaseQueryMagicallyGoFaster` property to `True`. Seriously though, do the obvious things. Test your code against a local database and compare times. Connect to that remote database using a management tool and compare times. That will make it clear whether the issue lies with the database or the application. You may be inexperienced at writing code but that doesn't mean that you can't still think logically.

Comment: @jmcilhinney LOL. Okey II tried with local mysql db. it's really fast. But remote database response is very slow. Why is this? And what to do? Another hosting or check up the ways to tune existing? 
thanks

Comment: How far away is the remote machine?  Test it with something trivial like `SELECT 1`.

Comment: @RickJames the web server is at CANADA(CrocWeb) and the remote PC is at India(Connection speed is 5 Mbps). ping replies 
byte=32 time=384ms TTL=44

 SELECT 1 took 139.558ms

Answer (score 2):

India:Canada -- 140ms seems reasonable.  This means that *every* query sent to the server will take at least that long.

As for the "5 seconds"...  Turn on the "General log" for a short while and run the app.  Then look through the log.  You *may* find that vb.net is injecting some extra commands, possibly in front of each query you run.  This would further slow down your application.  *If* that is the case, abandon vb.net, and be suspicious of *any* other 3rd party software.

I hope you are doing only one "connection" for an entire session?

Aside from that, the best thing to consider doing is to write Stored Routines (Procedures, Functions, Triggers, etc) whenever you need to perform more than one query in a row.  That way, you can issue one query instead of multiple SQL statements, thereby fewer roundtrips.

Comment: It's actually Problem with connection opening and closing the remote connection time. I am migrating the connection to JSON API with mysql.

Comment: What is "connection to JSON API"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed your comment(not shown notification).With "connection to JSON API"  I meant, not using mysql connection method anymore rather building an api in php to retrive data as JSON and execute queries. It's working and really faster comparing mysql Connection. But I'm having a new problem now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260386/vb-net-error-collecting-data-from-json-to-a-datagrid-from-a-different-form-th
thanks