# vb.net : Error Collecting data from JSON to a datagrid from a different form/ thread

Tags: multithreading, datagrid

I want to retrive data from JSON api and do other task while it's loading. 
I have written successful code in a form Module

```
Public Sub aquiredata(mygrid As DataGridView, sql As String, tablename As String)

    Dim table As DataTable
    Dim thread1 As New Thread(
      Sub()
          Try
              Dim json As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://ratnt.com/api.php/" & _
        tablename & "?query=" & Chr(34) & sql & Chr(34) & "&token=" & My.Settings.token) '
                  table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
                  MsgBox("table done")
              Finally
                  Invoke(Sub()
                             mygrid.DataSource = table
                         End Sub)
              End Try
          End Sub
        )
        thread1.Start()
    End Sub
```

but while I'm calling it from another form  with the datagrid of that form it shows

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."
```

(P.S. I have tried with backgroundworker but the reason I avoided that it's repetative for every form because the parsing result is only completed with the RunWorkerCompleted event.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed very simple thing
which is underlying in the message...

```
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created
```

So just a slight change
`mygrid.invoke` instead of `invoke` only
is working.

Thanks